# Covariance in generic parameter and convention based on parameter type

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I'm really struggling to create interface/convention based rules for FluentValidator. It has following class

```
   abstract class AbstractValidator<T>
    {

    IRuleBuilderInitial<T, TProperty> RuleFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
    ...
    }


public interface IWithPropertyA
{
  string PropertyA{get;set;}
}

public interface IWithPropertyB
{
 string PropertyB{get;set;}
}

public class Handler1Data: IWithPropertyA
{
 public string PropertyA {get;set;}
}
public class Handler2Data: IWithPropertyA, IWithPropertyB
{
 public string PropertyA {get;set;}
 public string PropertyB {get;set;}
}

public class Handler1 : AbstractValidator<Handler1Data> {}
public class Handler2 : AbstractValidator<Handler2Data> {}
```

I'm trying to create extension method which will basically check if generic argument implements specific interface and then adds rule to it:

```
public static void ValidateAll<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator)
        {

           (validator as AbstractValidator<IWithPropertyA>)?.RuleFor(x => x.PropertyA).NotEmpty().WithMessage("PropertyA Missing");
           (validator as AbstractValidator<IWithPropertyB>)?.RuleFor(x => x.PropertyB).NotEmpty().WithMessage("PropertyB Missing");
        }
```

The problem here is obviously AbstractValidator is not covariant so validator is not castable to neither `AbstractValidator<PropertyA>` nor `AbstractValidator<PropertyB>`. I've tried to create my own Base Validator like below and then create extension method based on that but I can't.

```
public interface IMyValidator<in T>
{
   void AddMyRule<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression) //it doesn't work because Expression<Func<T,Property> cannont be covariant
}

public abstract class MyBaseValidator<T>: AbstractValidator<T> ,IMyValidator<T>
{
   void AddMyRule<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
}
```

Method will be called in each Handler like this:

```
public class Handler1 : AbstractValidator<Handler1Data> {
  this.ValidateAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround which avoids using Expression which is obviously the issue here. The downfall of it is that we lose property name and we have to configure message manually.

```
 public interface IMyValidator<out T>
    {
        void AddMyRule<TProperty>(Func<T, TProperty> expression, string message);
    }

    public abstract class MyBaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>, IMyValidator<T>
        {
            public void AddMyRule<TProperty>(Func<T, TProperty> expression, string message)
            {
                var exp = FuncToExpression(expression);
                RuleFor(exp).NotEmpty().WithMessage(message);
            }

            private static Expression<Func<T, P>> FuncToExpression<T, P>(Func<T, P> f) => x => f(x);
        }

public static class Ext
    {
        public static void ValidateAll<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator)
        {
            (validator as IMyValidator<IWithPropertyA>)?.AddMyRule(x => x.PropertyA, "PropA Cant be empty");
            (validator as IMyValidator<IWithPropertyB>)?.AddMyRule(x => x.PropertyB, "PropB Cant be empty");
        }
    }

 public class Handler1 : MyBaseValidator<Handler1Data>
    {
        public Handler1()
        {
            this.ValidateAll();
        }
    }
    public class Handler2 : MyBaseValidator<Handler2Data> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean to write:

```
(validator as AbstractValidator<IWithPropertyA>)
    ?.RuleFor(x => x.PropertyA)
     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage("Property1 Missing");
```

Because `Property1` is not defined anywhere.